# How to prove vertex basis?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If $G = (V, E)$ is a simple, directed and acyclic graph. How can we prove that $B = \left\{{v \in V | d^-(v) = 0}\right\}$ is a vertex basis of G, and moreover it is the only vertex basis?

Please note that $d^-(v)$ is the in-degree of the vertex.

**EDIT:**

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a simple, directed and acyclic graph.  $\exists v \in V$, such that $d^-(v) = 0$, by the definition of vertex basis, this implies that $v \in B$ ($v$ is a vertex basis).

Let $v \in V \setminus B$, and we walk back from $v$ by traversing edges against their orientations. Using this process, we either reach a vertex in $B$, or a vertex previously reached. The latter part implies that there is a cycle and that $G$ is a cyclic graph, which contradicts our definition of G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: First show that every vertex of in-degree $0$ must belong to every vertex basis; this is immediate from the definition of *vertex basis*. Then let $v\in V\setminus B$, and ‘walk back’ from $v$ by traversing edges against their orientations. Show that this process must either reach a vertex in $B$, in which case $v$ is reachable from $B$, or return to a vertex previously reached; why is the latter impossible? This shows that $B$ is a vertex basis and is a subset of every vertex basis for $G$. Finally, use the ‘walking back’ argument to show that no vertex basis for $G$ can contain any vertex not in $B$.

**Added in response to the edit:** I gather that the first paragraph is an attempt to show that $B$ must be a subset of every vertex basis, but it doesn’t actually do that. To do that, you want to suppose that some $C\subseteq V$ is a vertex basis for $G$, let $v\in B$, and prove that $v\in C$. Suppose that $v\notin C$; then since $C$ is a vertex basis, there is a directed path from some $u\in C$ to $v$. But that means that the in-degree of $v$ is at least $1$, contradicting the assumption that $v\in B$. Thus, $v\in C$, and since $v$ was an arbitrary vertex of $B$, we’ve shown that $B\subseteq C$. That is, $B$ is a subset of every vertex basis for $G$.

In the second paragraph you need to justify the assertion that we reach either a vertex of $B$ or a vertex previously reached. I suggest organizing it as follows:

> Now we want to show that every vertex of $G$ is reachable from $B$. Let $v_0\in V\setminus B$. Since $v_0\notin B$, $\deg^-(v_0)\ge 1$, and there is a vertex $v_1$ such that $\langle v_1,v_0\rangle$ is an edge of $G$. If $v_1\in B$, we’ve shown that $v_0$ can be reached from $B$. If not, $\deg^-(v_1)\ge 1$, and there is a vertex $v_2$ such that $\langle v_2,v_1\rangle$ is an edge of $G$. Again, if $v_2\in B$, we have a path from $B$ to $v_0$, namely, $v_2,v_1,v_0$. If not, continue. If at any point we reach a vertex in $B$, we’re done: following the vertices in the opposite order gives us a path from $B$ to $v_0$.

Now explain why the only other possibility (besides reaching a vertex of $B$) is reaching a $v_k$ that you’d previously reached, so that you have a directed cycle, contrary to the hypothesis that the graph is acyclic. You should probably then explain why no vertex of $B$ is reachable from any other vertex of $B$; admittedly it’s pretty obvious, but play safe by mentioning it explicitly. Then you’ve proved that $B$ is vertex basis for $G$. Uniqueness is implicit in what’s already been proved, but again you should probably make it explicit.

> Suppose that $C$ is a vertex basis for $G$. We’ve shown that $B\subseteq C$. We’ve also shown that if $v\in V\setminus B$, then $v$ can be reached from $B$ and hence from $C$; by the definition of *vertex basis* this means that $v$ cannot be a member of $C$, so $C\cap(V\setminus B)=\varnothing$, and therefore $C\subseteq B$. Putting the pieces together, we see that $B=C$ and hence that $B$ is the unique vertex basis for $G$.

Comment: One thing that confuses me is that if we reach from any vertex $v\in V\setminus B$, a vertex in $B$, how can a vertex in $B$ has in-degree of $0$? Also, I don't exactly understand how to mathematically play with this `walk back` traversal.

Comment: @portal: (You have to use `\setminus` to get the set difference operator $\setminus$.) You’re walking back *against* the orientation of the edge, so when you reach a vertex of $B$, it’s along an edge that *leaves* that vertex. By *walking back* I mean following a walk in the digraph that you’d get if you turned all of the arrows around.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, we are moving in the opposite direction of each edge? Simply, like flipping the directions of each edge. And how will I write this mathematically, just like `walk back traversing the edges against the orientation?`. Regarding the second part, if we return to a vertex previously reached, does it mean that our graph is cyclic, and we have cycle somewhere?

Comment: @portal: For the first question: As an instructor I would accept that description, since I think it perfectly clear; others might be fussier. To play safe, you could let $G'$ be the same graph with the orientations reversed, and show that any walk from $v$ must either reach $B$ or intersect itself. For the second question, yes, that would mean that there must be a directed cycle.

Comment: Got it, I will try to write a proof, and and show it. In the meantime, can you at least check a similar question that I have. Where I think some of these techniques can also be applied partially: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476935/vertex-basis-and-graph-reduction

Comment: @portal: It may be a bit before I can get to it, but I do already have it open in another tab to take a look at it.

Comment: Please check my edit. I tried to do something, though, I don't know how good it is. If you can fix my proof, and complete it somehow, I would be really glad.

Comment: Any opinion Brian?

Comment: @portal: I’ve added a discussion of your edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, two quick questions. In the first part of the discussion, when you say "let $v \in B$, and prove that $v \in C$", Then you contradict, saying that $B$ cannot contain vertexes with degree greater than 0. You already assume that B is a subset of every vertex base, right? The second question, in the last part when you wrote "by the definition of vertex basis this means that $v$ cannot be a member of $C$". You are assuming the definition of vertex base that states that a vertex base is minimal with respect to the subset relation ($\subset$)?

Comment: @portal: No, I didn’t already assume that $B$ is a subset of every vertex basis: that’s exactly what I’m proving in that paragraph. \\ My definition of vertex basis is *a set$ $B$ $of vertices such that every vertex of the graph can be reached from$ $B$, $but no vertex of$ $B$ $can be reached from any other vertex of$ $B$. This does, however, imply that $B$ is minimal with respect to $\subseteq$, yes.